# When a subquery uses a value from parent query in ON conditions it produces 'Unknown column' error

Tags: mysql, join, subquery

If I execute the following query, it works fine:

```sql
SELECT
CASE WHEN (SELECT COUNT(*)
    FROM rates r
    LEFT JOIN promotions_rates pr
        ON r.id = pr.rate_id
    WHERE pr.promo_id IS NULL
    AND pr.promo_id = promotions.id)
    > 0 THEN 'N' ELSE 'Y' END AS 'all_rates_selected'
FROM promotions
```

However if I rearrange it to put `promotions.id` in the `ON` part instead of `WHERE` like this:

```sql
SELECT
    CASE WHEN (SELECT COUNT(*)
        FROM rates r
        LEFT JOIN promotions_rates pr
            ON r.id = pr.rate_id
            AND pr.promo_id = promotions.id
        WHERE pr.promo_id IS NULL)
        > 0 THEN 'N' ELSE 'Y' END AS 'all_rates_selected'
FROM promotions
```

I get the error `Unknown column 'promotions.id' in 'on clause'`. In both cases, I am using `promotions.id` in the sub-query, but it works in the `WHERE` but not in the `ON`. Why would it work with one and not with the other?

Is there another way I can do the second query to count the `NULL` values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at this example, maybe it is simpler to understand:

```
SELECT *
FROM rates r 
LEFT JOIN promotions_rates pr ON r.id=pr.rate_id,
promotions p
WHERE pr.promo_id=p.id
```

This will success because join condition doesn't include column from promotions. Mysql joins `rates` and `promotions_rates` together, creates a temporary table and search with where conditions in the temporary table and promotions.

```
SELECT *
FROM rates r 
LEFT JOIN promotions_rates pr ON r.id=pr.rate_id AND pr.promo_id=p.id,
promotions p
WHERE pr.promo_id IS NULL
```

This will fail because when mysql try to join `rates` and `promotions_rates` together, it doesn't know anything about `promotions`. Basically, Your second sample is doing the same thing. If you want it to be success, you should join `promotions` too.

Like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM rates r 
LEFT JOIN promotions_rates pr ON r.id=pr.rate_id AND pr.promo_id=p.id
LEFT JOIN promotions p ON pr.promo_id=p.id
WHERE pr.promo_id IS NULL
```

I haven't run the first query but I think this query will always return 'Y', because in the first query ,you are trying to search for records with id 'null' in the `promotions` table.

If your 'Y' stands for 'all rates are related to some promotions', You may want to remove the `AND pr.promo_id = promotions.id` part. If your 'Y' stands for 'all rates are related to this promotion', maybe you can use this query:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN(p_count.count=r_count.count THEN 'Y' ELSE 'N' END AS all_rates_selected
FROM promotions
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT count(*) as count,p.id as id
    FROM promotions p
    LEFT JOIN promotions_rates pr ON p.id = pr.promo_id
    LEFT JOIN rates r ON r.id=pr.rate_id
    GROUP BY p.id
) p_count ON promotions.id = p_count.id,
(
    SELECT count(*) as count
    FROM rates
) r_count
```

I haven't tested this code since I don't have any data. Please let me know if I am wrong, thank you.